# ¿Cómo le puedo asignar a un usuario de MYSQL que pueda acceder a cualquier BD?

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de crear tablas en una BD de mysql con la información de Otras tablas de OTRA BD..  para ello necesito que el usuario que estoy usando tenga acceso a diferentes Bases de datos de mi mismo servidor. Para dar un ejemplo:

```
 CREATE TABLE bdreportes.destinoProspectos AS 
  SELECT * FROM countier.prospectos
```

aquí estoy "tratando" de crear una copia de la tabla "prospectos" de la base de datos "countier" con el nombre "destinoProspectos" pero en la base de datos "bdreportes", al tratar de ejecutar este comando obtengo el mensaje:

INSERT,CREATE command denied to user 'countier'@'189.143.171.21' for table 'destino'

Digamos que es "lógico" por que el usuario "countier" no tiene los suficientes privilegios para poder tambien "manipular" o "accesar" a la base de datos "bdreportes",
no sé como hacer el comando para darle esos privilegios al usuario "countier".
¿Alguna orientación? He intentado el siguiente comando:

```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'countier'@'216.70.69.75'
```

pero me arroja el error:

Access denied for user 'countier'@'%' (using password: YES)

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: desde que usuario tratas de asignarle permisos?? obviamente no puede asignarse permisos a si mismo...

Comment: Pues desde el usuario countier.....yo creo que si se puede asignar permisos, por que?

Comment: si pudieras asignar permisos al mismo usuario que esta logueado, a cualquier tabla, entonces cualquier usuario que logre acceso con cualquier usuario podria ver cualquier tabla del sistema. El acceso lo tiene que asignar el usuario dueño de la tabla, o un usuario con permisos sobre la misma...

Comment: a ver deja lo intento

Comment: Ya lo logré gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

La solución a este problema era crear un usuario por medio del panel Plesk donde me da la opción de decir que dicho usuario tendra acceso a todas las bases de datos existentes y con eso ya puedo usar dicho usuario para poder interactuar entre Bases de Datos. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]